# Set Ringtone in Android

Tags: java, android

How do I set ringtone programatically in android ?
I found a thread mentioning this same problem, but there is no accepted answer to it. Any help would be Greatly appreiated

```
void changeRingtone(String title,File file){
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,file.getAbsolutePath() );
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, title);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Unknown");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    this,
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                    newUri
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong, approach Developer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This throws the exception that _data is not mutable

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mutation of _data is not allowed.
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:557)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2200)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2162)
    at com.codex.dendenring.MainActivity.changeRingtone(MainActivity.java:130)
    at com.codex.dendenring.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$com-codex-dendenring-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:60)
    at com.codex.dendenring.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to set MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA information. Check out the documentation examples.

[Media Store Examples](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)

Comment: You were right, I didn't, just need to specify the URI.